# Ubuntu force date and time if NTP can't update

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4. Since it doesn't have a RTC, the date/time can't update unless it is on the network and can get to an NTP server.

Sometimes this system is booted up on a network where it can get to an NTP server, but sometimes it is booted up and disconnected from a network, or on a closed network with no NTP servers.

Is there a way to manually *force* the current date and time, but keep NTP active so if next time the system is booted it will sync if it can get to an NTP server? If I try to set the time (using `timedatectl`) with NTP active I get the error:

```
Failed to set time: Automatic time synchronization is enabled
```

If I turn off NTP, I can set the time, but as soon as I re-enable NTP it seems to reset the time to when it was last synced, losing the time I just set.

Is there any way around this? Keep NTP active (even through it *currently* can't get to a server) but manually give the system a more accurate date/time?

## UPDATE

I think I found the file NTP is using to get the date/time when it is started. It looks like it pulls this from `/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock`. If I turn off NTP, set the date/time I want, `touch` this file, and then restart NTP, it keeps the time I set.

Is this the best way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script (or standalone command) if you want to synchronize the date:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

Taken from this [link](https://gist.github.com/iliion/c29b0bb0a4b2fd3160e612c64110c112)